# jQuery 1.4.2 JSON format breaking what used to work in 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-1.4

I just upgraded my jQuery from 1.3.2 to 1.4.2, and I think it's giving me some issues. I have a `$.post()` function that calls a controller method and passes along some data that I format like so:

```
$.post(url, { arrayParam: myArray, param2: false }, someCallback, 'html');
```

In Firebug, the POST says the parameters in 1.3.2 look like this:

```
arrayParam: 100
arrayParam: 101 (etc..)
```

But for 1.4.2 they look like this:

```
arrayParam[]: 100
```

This is breaking my controller which is expecting a `List<Int32>` for `arrayParam` (and is causing some JSON issues around the codebase). Is there a way around this without either reverting back to 1.3.2 or reprogramming all of my controllers??

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

jQuery's ajax methods use $.param() on the data that is passed in.

See [jquery param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for more info.

Here is your fix:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```